# no ros-foxy-ros-base for armhf, why?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On focal, why aren't there any ros-foxy-* packages for armhf architecture, like `ros-foxy-ros-base`?
There are just a few ament_cmake ones.
There must be a reson to this, I don't know yet.

Location of packages to look is [here](http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-armhf/Packages) as described in the [install manual](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Debians/#setup-sources)

Appreciate any kind of tip.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371683/no-ros-foxy-ros-base-for-armhf,-why?/) by [woodz](https://answers.ros.org/users/68148/woodz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP 2000: Foxy Fitzroy (May 2020 - May 2023)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#foxy-fitzroy-may-2020-may-2023), `armhf` (or `arm32` I believe it's called in that REP), is *Tier 3* on all supported OS (Ubuntu, Debian and WebOS).

That means there are no binary packages available, and the `S` in the table means users are required to build them from source.

> There are just a few ament_cmake ones

that's probably because those are Python/CMake packages, which don't require any additional builds to be usable on `arm32`.

You can also see this on [repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_foxy_ubhf.html](http://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_foxy_ubhf.html): note there are almost no green squares in the `Fhf` column.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2021-02-12**:
To add to this, here is a [discourse post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/potential-downgrade-of-arm32-support-to-tier-3/14136) regarding the tier downgrade for arm32 support.